# Node.js request module multiple parameters with same name

Tags: node.js

I am trying to send a http request from my node app. The request has multiple parameters with same name. I am having trouble on the receiving end.

The parameters are not coming in the desired format.

Request:

```
city[]=1
city[]=2
```

Here's what I see on server when I send a normal fetch request from front end.

```
city: [1, 2]
```

Here's what I am seeing on the server side when I use another endpoint to make a request to the same endpoint as above using node's request module.

```
city[][0]: 1
city[][1]: 2
```

Here's the HAR object I am using to make the request from the server.

```
{
  "method": "POST",
  "queryString": [],
  "headers": [
    {
      "name": "content-type",
      "value": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    }
  ],
  "url": "http://localhost:3001/api/v2/roles/test",
  "postData": {
    "mimeType": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
    "params": [
      {
        "name": "city[]",
        "value": "1"
      },
      {
        "name": "city[]",
        "value": "2"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Why are you sending a request with multiple params with the same name?

Comment: Because it's an array and the standard way to send a list over http

Answer (score 0):

The `city[]` is an odd parameter for a javascript object, as square brackets are basically reserved for arrays. If you sent multiple `city` params in your request, I would expect to see a `city` array. *I'd suggest just doing it without the square braces in the parameter name.*

However, if you're stuck with that, perhaps you can access the params object on your request using some string notation (made up example):

```
req.params['city[]'][0]
```

Either way, be sure to check if you parameter is an array or not. If you only send one `city` query params, you'd end up with `city: 1` not `city: [1]`

Comment: I've tried many number of things. The both with and without []. It never seems to work as expected. But it works just fine when working with fetch API.

Comment: Are you using a library to parse the request body? Like [body-parser](https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser) or [multiparty](https://github.com/pillarjs/multiparty) (or others)

Comment: Yeah I was using body-parser. But I ended up using node-fetch to make the request and it worked pretty simply.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up a module named `node-fetch`. It was pretty simple and painless.

```
const params = new URLSearchParams(init);

params.append('foo[]', 1);
params.append('foo[]', 2);

fetch('url/here's, params);
```